# How can we construct a ZKPoK which hides both $x$ and the witness $W_x$ in dynamic accumulators?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, pairings, anonymity, accumulators, zero-knowledge

Consider a verification equation $ e(\Delta,\tilde{G}) = e(W_x,x\tilde{G}+pk_{acc})$  from a pairing based accumulator which uses the value $x$ and the corresponding witness $W_x$  to verify that a value $x$ is accumulated in the accumulator $\Delta$.

For anonymous credential system for **multishow unlinkability**, we often need to present a ZKPoK $\pi_v$ showing that $x$ is accumulated in $\Delta$ **without revealing** $x$ and the **witness** $W_x$.

\begin{equation}
            \label{piverification}
           \begin{split}
            \pi_{v} &= \mathrm{ZKPoK}\{(x,W_x):  e(\Delta,\tilde{G}) = e(W_x,x\tilde{G}+pk_{acc})
            \wedge Commit(x,\tilde{r})\}.
        \end{split}
       \end{equation}

How can we construct a ZKPoK which hides both $x$ and $W_x$ ?